# Scroll not working in python selenium code

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote the code like this.

However, if there is an element of the conditional statement, after clicking, scrolling is operated on the website. It does not work and there is no error code.

The upper code outside the conditional statement works. What's the reason ?

```
                    count = 0

                    while count < 10:
                        
                        try:
                            element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.txt.elss[href="' + self.URL_input.text() + '"]')
                            time.sleep(2)
                           
                            print(self.URL_input.text())
                           
                            element.click()
                            time.sleep(10)
     
                            for i in range(0, 10000,10):
                                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {})".format(i))
                            self.output_box.insertPlainText("1.\n")
                            QApplication.processEvents()      
                            random_delay = random.uniform(5, 10)
                          
                            #driver.quit()
                            break
                        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                        
                            element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn_next')
                            time.sleep(2)
                        
                            element.click()
                            time.sleep(2)
                            count += 1
                    self.output_box.insertPlainText("10.\n")
                    QApplication.processEvents()   
                    time.sleep(5)
                self.output_box.insertPlainText("end.\n")
                def scroll_down():
                    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 50);")

         
                    scroll_time = random.uniform(2, 5)

                    start_time = time.time()  
                    while True:
                        scroll_down()
                        time.sleep(0.3)  # 1

                                        # 
                        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
                        if elapsed_time >= scroll_time:
                                break  
                self.output_box.insertPlainText("\n" + formatted_now + " End!!.")
                QApplication.processEvents()  # 
                driver.quit()
```

Comment: Post the URL and the whole code you've tried so far, with the above code, we can't debug anything.

Comment: i solved it
That's because you haven't specified a new tab.